# How to setup LBaaS with Openstack and Juju?

Tags: networking, juju, openstack, openstack-autopilot

We have our Openstack deployed via Landscape and Juju and are trying to setup Load Balancer as a Service within the cloud.

We have found that we need to configure openstack-dashboard to show the Load Balancer options, which is done with

```
juju set openstack-dashboard neutron-network-lb=True
```

Openstack documentation says we also need to configure multiple parameters on the neutron-openvswitch machine (as seen here http://docs.openstack.org/admin-guide-cloud/content/install_neutron-lbaas-agent.html)

But with Juju managing the configuration, how do we do that? Juju charm for Neutron has no such options to set.  Do we even need to do that or with Juju does setting the openstack-dashboard automatically enable it on the neutron-openvswitch as well?

Answer (score 2):

We figured it out.  We needed to add configuration to neutron-openvswitch to enable LBaaS agent.

1. `juju ssh neutron-openvswitch/0`
2. Install lb agent

   `sudo apt-get install neutron-lbaas-agent`
3. Modify /etc/neutron/neutron.conf by adding the following lines

   `service_provider = LOADBALANCER:Haproxy:neutron.services.loadbalancer.drivers.haproxy.plugin_driver.HaproxyOnHostPluginDriver:default
   service_plugins = lbaas`
4. Restart LB agent service

   `sudo neutron-lbaas-agent restart`
5. This works with our previous step already being done

`juju set openstack-dashboard neutron-network-lb=True`

but the order doesn't matter.  Dashboard can be modified after the neutron configuration changes as well.

Comment: Very cool, though, keep in mind that if any charm hooks are fired for neutron `/etc/neutron/neutron.conf` modifications made manually could potentially be lost. My suggestion would be to file a bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/charms/+source/neutron-openvswitch to get this support added into the charm.